# What is the most effective way for a Dialog to interact with an array adapter of a (parent) activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

The way my dialog is set up currently, it *is supposed* to take the values from the EditTexts and save in into a database (a process simplified through [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html)), then place the newly created `SubjectInfo` object into the RecyclerView. The way the `notifyDataSetChanged();` is included gives me errors concerning the Thread (basically no thread is waiting upon the change in the data set). SO, I have two paths as I see it, but I'm still confused as to how each approach would work.

Option 1: Somehow revoke the `onCreate()` method in the `SubjectManagerActivity` so that the adapter responds to the new database. (How to revoke an onCreate method?)

Option 2: Create a custom Dialog Fragment Activity. Does this navigate back up to recreate the parent activity?

Please help explain how to make the `notifyDataSetChanged();` respond, because once that line is removed, there are no errors, but I can't see the new Subject card until I restart the app.

Here is my code:

```
public class SubjectManagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static ArrayList<SubjectInfo> subjectList = new ArrayList<SubjectInfo>();
    public static FloatingActionButton fabCreateSubject;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_manager);
     RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.subject_card_list);
     recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
     LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
     llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
     recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
     subjectList = getSubjectInfoArrayList();
     SubjectAdapter sa = new SubjectAdapter(subjectList);
     recList.setAdapter(sa);

     fabCreateSubject = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_create_subject);
     fabCreateSubject.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubjectManagerActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View alertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_subject_dialog, null);

            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            build.setView(alertview);
            final EditText inputSubjectName = (EditText) alertview.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_subject_card_name);
            final EditText inputSubjectGrade = (EditText) alertview.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_subject_card_grade);

            build.setTitle("Add Subject")
                    .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String enteredSubjectName = inputSubjectName.getText().toString();
                            boolean enteredSubjectIsArchived = false;

                            if((!(inputSubjectName.getText().toString().equals("")))) {
                                SubjectInfo si = new SubjectInfo(enteredSubjectName, enteredSubjectIsArchived);
                                si.save();
                            } 
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
public ArrayList<SubjectInfo> getSubjectInfoArrayList(){
    ArrayList<SubjectInfo> sial= new ArrayList<SubjectInfo>();
    List<SubjectInfo> sil = SubjectInfo.listAll(SubjectInfo.class);
    sial.addAll(sil);
    notifyDataSetChanged;
    return sial;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out often the most effective way to deal with an issue is to trust in your code and research to make it work! For anyone else with a similar issue, I included this code:

```
si.save();
subjectList.add(si);
sa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The method `notifyDataSetChanged();` had to be directed to an adapter, which is the container of the Thread. Though the adapter isn't being populated from the `getSubjectInfoArrayList()` method in real-time (when the dialog is prompted), the ArrayList is still acquiring the same value and when the app is reopened, it can populate the adapter from the database (and in turn, the same get( ) method).